# Submodule of finite module over noetherian ring finite (Constructive proof wanted)

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

Let $A$ be a noetherian ring and $M$ a finite $A$-module. That
is there exist $m_1,...m_k \in M$ which generate $M$ as $A$-module.
Let $N \subset M$ a submodule of $M$. It's a well known fact that
since $A$ noetherian every submodule of finite $A$-module is
also finite.

Although I found plenty proofs like
[this one](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00IJ) no one I found was constructive, that is no one contained a direct method
to construct explicitely a set of generators $n_1,..., n_s$ of $N$ from
$m_1,...m_k \in M$.

Question: Does there exist a constructive proof of quoted result containing  a method to construct generators of $N$ explicitly?

Comment: Your method would require a constructive representation of the fact that $A$ is noetherian. There very likely is some computational content to be derived from this classical result, but teasing it out may be quite complicated (following some kind of [proof mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_mining) approach).

Comment: To expand on @RobArthan's comment: it seems to me standard proofs of this fact are actually pretty close to constructive modulo the fact that $A$'s noetherianness is not explicitly constructive. In particular you need a way to produce a finite list of generators for an ideal of $A$ given some other description of this ideal. For example, one way I could argue this theorem to myself is to induct on the number of generators. You can already see the issue in the base case: $M=Am_1\subset M$; then $M \cong A/I$ where $I$ is the annihilator of $m_1$. Any submodule of $M$ is then (isomorphically) an

Comment: ideal of $A/I$, which corresponds by the correspondence theorem to an ideal $J$ of $A$ containing $I$. *At this point, one invokes the noetherian hypothesis on $A$* to assert that $J$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module, and the images of these generators in $M\cong A/I$ then generate the desired submodule. To make this argument constructive, we need a way to get from whatever description we have of our target submodule to a description of $J$, and then to generators for $J$. So, how was the submodule described to us? If it was given to us in terms of, say, infinitely many generators,

Comment: then one necessary step is that we need an explicit way to pass from an infinite set of generators for an ideal of $A$, to a finite set. Alternatively, if our desired submodule is given to us as the kernel of some explicitly described module map, then we need a way to get from an explicitly described ring homomorphism out of $A$ to a finite generating set for its kernel. Either of these is the type of thing @RobArthan was referring to as "a constructive representation of the fact that $A$ is noetherian." If you are happy to accept oracles for these tasks in your algorithm, I'm confident you

Comment: can get a constructive proof just by digging through the standard proofs, replacing calls to $A$'s noetherianness with these oracles. (There will also need to be some thought given to the type of data via which the module $M$ and its target submodule are handed to you. E.g., is $M$ finitely presented by a matrix over $A$?)

Comment: @Ben: In your first comment you probably wanted to write $N \subset Am_1 = M$ in order to study submodules as ideals of $A/I$, right?

Comment: @IsaktheXI I actually meant what I wrote, but I apologize for the unclear notation! I should've just written $M=Am_1$. What I was intending for the notation to acknowledge was that in all cases $Am_1\subset M$, but in the base case (1 generator), then $M$ actually equals $Am_1$. Again, sorry this was unclear. (Yes, I wanted to go to this case so we could look at submodules as ideals of $A/I$.)